# Rspec - How to write specs for a chain of methods

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm learning rspec, and I'm wondering what the most effective way to write specs for a method that calls a chain of other methods.  For example:

```
class Example1
  def foo(dependency)
     dependency.bar("A")
     dependency.baz("B")
     dependency.bzz("C")
  end
end
```

Ideally I would like to write specs like this:

```
it "should call bar" do
   ex = Example1.new
   dep = mock
   dep.should_receive(:bar).with("A")
   ex.foo(dep)
end
it "should call baz"
   ... 
it "should call bzz"
   ...
```

When I do that, however, I (understandably) get exceptions like 'unexpected method call baz'.

So what's the best way to deal with that?   I have come up with a couple of ideas but I don't know if any of them are good.

1. Make the mock dependency an "as_null_object" so it ignores the extra calls.  (Down side - if I was calling unwanted random stuff on that object, I wouldn't know it)
2. Stub out the two unused dependency method calls in each spec  (Down side - feels very DRY)
3. Stub out all three dependency calls in a 'before'  (Down side - puts a lot of junk in the 'before')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have already worked out which options RSpec gives you. I would go with option 1 and use `as_null_object`. It's true that you might be missing other random method calls on that object but I would be ok with that if the point of each of these tests was simply to assert that a particular method was being called, especially if I have higher level integration tests covering this method.

If you really need to verify that no other methods are called on `dependency` then option 3 may make sense but such tests can be brittle when implementation changes.

As an aside, to make your test a little simpler you can use `subject` to avoid explicitly instantiating `Example1` (assuming you are using a `describe Example1` block), e.g.:

```
subject.foo(dep)
```

(However see discussion in comments - an implicit subject can hide intention).

Comment: RSpec's author advises against explicit use of subject: http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/

Comment: I was suggesting an implicit subject rather than an explicit one. David Chelimsky says that we should avoid explicit subjects (in most cases). He seems a bit less worried about implicit ones though he is still not too keen on them either. I didn't realise that subject was originally introduced to support `it { should ... }` style examples and not meant to be seen though.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>RSpec has a feature called stub_chain: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-0/docs/stubs/stub-a-chain-of-methods</strike>

What about testing them all in one example?

```
it "should call bar"
   ex = Example1.new
   dep = mock
   dep.should_receive("bar").with("A")
   dep.should_receive("baz").with("B")
   dep.should_receive("bzz").with("C")
   ex.foo(dep)
end
```

I believe you can use RSpec to verify the order in which they are called, if that matters.

However, this kind of approach often indicate that there is a problem with how the code is written, e.g. a Law Of Demeter violation. In your example, `foo` should be a methed on the dependency's class.

Comment: Interesting!  But it doesn't seem like that applies in this case because my chain is not x.y.z -- it's just one method call after another.  Unless I'm missing what you're getting at?

Comment: You're right, I hadn't considered putting them all in one spec.  I'm more used to having one assert per spec.   Your comment about LoD is valid, but this was a simplified example.  In reality, class Example1 is orchestrating things across different classes.

Comment: I would say there's actually just one assertion here - the implicit verify that RSpec does at the end of the example.

Answer (score 1):

I would test this code in this way:

```
describe "checking foo method" do

  before(:each) do
    @ex = Example1.new
    @test = ClassOfDependency.any_instance
    @test.as_null_object
  end

  after(:each) do
    @ex.foo(dependency)
  end

  it "should call bar method" do
    @test.should_receive(:bar).with("A")
  end

  it "should call baz method" do
    @test.should_receive(:baz).with("B")
  end

  it "should call bzz method" do
    @test.should_receive(:bzz).with("C")
  end
end
```

But I'm not sure that it will work, hope it'll give you some ideas.